# How to concatenate a single white space using Liquid

Tags: liquid

I have 3 fields, first, middle and last name. I want to use `Liquid` template to concatenate the three fields to created a full name.

Here is what I have done

```
{% assign firstName = 'John' %}
{% assign middleName = '' %}
{% assign lastName = 'Smith' %}

{% assign title = '' %}

{% if firstName != nil and firstName != '' %}
{% assign title = title | concat: firstName | concat: ' ' %}
{% endif %}

{% if middleName != nil and middleName != '' %}
{% assign title = title | concat: middleName | concat: ' ' %}
{% endif %}

{% if lastName != nil and lastName != '' %}
{% assign title = title | concat: lastName %}
{% endif %}

{{ title | strip }}
```

The above generates `JohnSmith` with no space in between. How can I correctly generate the fullname using Liquid syntax? Is there a shorter way of doing the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

```
{% assign firstName = 'John' %}
{% assign middleName = '' %}
{% assign lastName = 'Smith' %}
      
{% assign title = '' %}
      
{% if firstName != nil and firstName != '' %}
{% assign title = title | append: firstName | append: ' ' %}
{% endif %}
      
{% if middleName != nil and middleName != '' %}
{% assign title = title | append: middleName | append: ' ' %}
{% endif %}
      
{% if lastName != nil and lastName != '' %}
{% assign title = title | append: lastName %}
{% endif %}
      
{{ title | strip }}
```

**concat** filter (combines) an array with another array. The resulting array contains all the elements of the original arrays.
try using **append** filter instead.
or if for some reason you want to use concat you can add **join** filter like so:
`{{ title | join : ' ' | strip }}`